# Ambiguous expression type error ( Swift 2 )

Tags: ios, swift

I have an alert popup to which I add an action that has a callback where an exception might be thrown.

The thing is that in the code below there is an ambiguous expression type error near *style: .Default*. This apparently happens because of an error: if I remove the whole catch block and replace *try* with *try!* - the error is gone.

I'm confused and need your help!

```
let submitButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] _ in
        let answerField = ac.textFields![0]


        do {
            try self.submitAnswer(answerField.text!)
        } catch let error as UserInputError {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you still have the error if you use `UIAlertActionStyle.Default` instead of `.Default`?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it but the error persists.

Comment: My bad, seems obvious. Anyway, what is the signature of `submitAnswer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The real problem is that your `catch`
statement is not "exhaustive". The compiler does not know that 
`UserInputError` is the only possible error thrown.

This should fix it:

```
do {
    try self.submitAnswer(answerField.text!)
} catch let error as UserInputError {
    // a UserInputError
} catch let error {
    // some other error
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped! I completely forgot about it!